# Issue with Duplicate query strings in the URL when generating the URL dynamically in the expression of the field on the SSRS report,

Tags: reporting-services

Can any body help on the following issues.

SSRS reports (.rdl) files have been implemeted in the Sharepoint integrated mode.
Report have be deployed to share point library (reports Library)
Created the aspx and added the report viewer webpart to the page
And in the report path of report viewer webpart , it was refered to the path of .rdl file in the report folder with fully qualified url as follows
Internal site URL  - http://intcollaborate/sites//reports/
we have some Hyperlinks on the report , these hyper links are pointing to the another aspx page which again shows some other report configured in the same way as above.
apart from the Internal site, there is another site EKWS site which will point to the same code to which Internal site is pointing.

Here is the actual problem. --- Out side Users will access our EKWS Site/FBA Site. When user clicks onthe Hyperlinks on the report, it is pointing to the internal site URL aspx page (because the report viwer is placed in the iframe by Sharepoint, this is the behaviour of sharepoint). This should point to the EKWS/FBA site URL/aspx page, Then the User is prompting for credentials. AS the authentication process is different for both internal site and external site.

Please let us Know how to solve this problem...

We tried to resolve this problem in the following way. But it is duplicating the Query string inthe URL.

we wrote the expression on the hyperlink field in the SSRS report, where it will check for the user and decide if he is internal user or external user

and based on that , URL is generating dynamically(Inernal URL /EKWS(FBA) URL ) with help of expresssion. But the Query string is duplicating inthe URL.

Here is the expression code

Iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "RPL", Iif(UserId Like "user:*", Parameters!InernalURL,Parameters!FBAURL) +  Parameters!SiteRelativeURL.Value + "/page1.aspx?ID=" + Fields!fieldName1.Value + "&Name=" + Fields!Fieldname2.Value  , Nothing)

Please help in suppressing the duplicating query strings. Or else please suggest the right appraoch

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be a known issue that they are working on...

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/618500/reportviewer-in-sharepoint-action-url-parameters-are-duplicated

I have heard that the issue does not happen on links across servers.

You can use a relative address to get to something within the same site.

But relative addresses don't seem to work across sites within the same server :-( maybe there is an IIS config that would allow that though. (I know there is an allow relative addressing setting in IIS but I don't know that this is the only factor)